# Hopping Gateways in a Multi-gateway Network?

Tags: linux, ip, routing, lan, gateway

I'm on a network that has multiple gateways, and it seems that my machine connects to a different gateway than what my phone does. I'm curious as to how I may switch to another gateway. I've tried disconnecting and reconnecting, but I'm not assigned a different IP (I assume that I've leased a specific IP for a given time and cannot switch in this method). Is it possible to force a connection in a different gateway? I tried using `route` to add a gateway, but my destination address restricts me to only using a specific gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are quite simple, really:

```
   sudo ip route del default 
   sudo ip route add default via Ip.Add.OfNew.Gateway
```

Be careful, though. It is possible your sysadmin has implemented a series of checks which make this re-direction impossible. For instance, he could have a firewall (*iptables*) checking on the MAC address of clients, which refuses to forward the traffic of all clients, except those explicitly permitted. So he might have decided that all mobile devices go through gateway 1, while all pcs go through gateway 2, where more severe controls on the activities carried out (no chats, no IRC, no facebook, no porn, no shooting the breeze) are enforced.

So, even though those two commands are absolutely correct, yet you may fail to reach the WAN.

If this were indeed the case, you might listen to generic traffic, find someone whose traffic is passing through the gateway you are interested in, then change your pc's MAC ddress (it's called *spoofing*) to be identical to that of the allowed machine, and then give yourself a *static* IP address again identical to that of the spoofed machine. Thus you will appear, to the gateway you want to go through, identical to an allowed machine, nd you will be allowed to pass through.

Have fun with this, but do not abuse it.

EDIT:

Your comment shows that your gateway lies in a different subnet than your pc. You will have to give yourself a static ip in the appropriate range. You may try as:

```
   sudo service network-manager stop
   sudo ip link set dev eth0 down
   sudo ip addr flush dev eth0
   sudo ip addr add 10.1.224.177/24 dev eth0
   sudo ip link set dev eth0 up
```

Now change the default gateway to 10.1.22.1 as above, and try again. If this does not work, you may want to substitute *177* with some other number which you know is not already occupied.

Comment: I appreciate the solution, but I'm still not reaching the WAN. I was hoping that I could achieve a connection through a specific gateway solely through my machine, not depending on info of other machines. If I don't have another machine to spoof from, I don't want to be out of luck. I tried what you recommended, and it changed the gateway, but my destination is the same, locking me from the WAN. When I run `ifconfig` my wireless device tells me 10.1.243.11, while my destination address from `route -n` is 10.1.224.0 and my gateway is 10.1.224.1.

Comment: @Zulfe Pls see my edit.